# Why only score is auto-updated via AJAX?

Tags: support, comments, voting, accepted-answer, live-refresh

I accidentally opened answer given to my question it two browser tabs. I upvoted answer, accepted it and left comment. When I closed first tab, and saw the second tab, I noticed, that only score (upvote) was auto-updated (refreshed) there via AJAX. Answer did not reflected (auto-updated) acceptance state and given comment. Why is that?

Comment: That's weird. All of these things should refresh automatically.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sounds great. Care to rewrite this as an answer to get some rep?

Answer (score 6):

The API only ever refreshes things that *others* (can) change; your own posts and comments are not included. This is probably done to avoid excessive bandwidth; why load something again you just posted to the server and thus is most likely already present on the current page?

So when you have a question open in multiple tabs and you comment on the post, the other tab(s) won't be notified. Post an answer? At best you'll get the AJAX-driven *1 new answer has been posted* message bar along the top in the other tabs.

When someone else also posts, and you load those extra comments or answers, your own content will also be loaded. Votes are something collectively changed and so the websocket doesn't filter those changes.