# Double accepted answers

Tags: bug, accepted-answer, live-refresh

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open two tabs with the same question.
2. Tab 1: Mark some answer as accepted.
3. Get another answer.
4. Tab 2: Mark some answer as accepted.
5. Tab 1: Press the "1 more answer" button.

What you'll get:

[image]!

Comment: Now reload the page. There is only one accepted answer.

Comment: Three downvotes, no single comment. What's wrong?

Comment: Voting on Meta is different; I think people are disagreeing it is a bug worth fixing or stating it is a bug at all.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, I see.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I guess, the several year long bug with list rendering in markdown will get the same reaction, won't it?

Comment: 'bug with list rendering'? What bug'd that be? The one where people misunderstand the semantics of a list with a code sample embedded in the list item, or are we talking about something different?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Like that: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VWG0X.png . Try the same on http://dillinger.io/ for example.

Comment: A list item is only a list item when you have both a number *and* the text to be part of the paragraph. Until you have text, the number is not a list item.

Comment: Besides, you are now touching upon a fundamental problem with Markdown: it is under-specified and there is no official test suite. Stack Exchange partnered with GitHub and others to change that, see http://commonmark.org/ and [Will CommonMark be adopted for SE?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238957)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, but in CommonMark it works in the same way it's done at dillinger.io, not like on StackOverflow.

Comment: Then, *eventually*, the behaviour will probably change to be compliant with CommonMark.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have found ways to break the expectations of the websocket live-refresh model. Only one answer is accepted, but because *you accepted the answer* the live refresh ignores the change. It is not the [only thing live-refresh ignores](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271460/why-only-score-is-auto-updated-via-ajax/271508#271508).

Refresh the page and you'll see there is only one accepted answer; the one you accepted last gets the mark and the +15 points, the other answerer lost the +15 again.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Am I wrong in that it's a bug in a live-refresh?

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph: not a bug but a limitation. Don't expect multiple tabs on the same question to take your own changes into account.

Comment: I don't see a limitation there. It's pretty easy to broadcast such messages to every tab on the user side.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph: I don't know enough about the backend and what optimisation choices have been made. Perhaps in a world of infinite resources that is trivial to implement, but when you get millions of page views *per day* there are limits to be taken into account.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294342/how-did-this-question-get-two-accepted-answers?cb=1