# How did this question get two accepted answers?

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250633/python-dictionary-with-list-of-keys) appears to have two accepted answers! How does this happen?

Here's a screenshot in case it changes:

[image]

Comment: Timeline looks alright... no! https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30250633/timeline

Comment: Fwiw, both answers have `is_accepted:true` in the API [`/questions/answers`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-questions#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=30250633&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true), although the earlier one is identified as the accepted one in [`/questions`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=30250633&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Comment: I guess it's a dictionary of accepted answers?

Comment: I smell a race condition.  Curious bug.

Comment: Let's write two answers here and you try to reproduce ;-)

Comment: I wonder how this happened.. Did OP click the accept button on both of them within a short period of time ? I tried that, can't reproduce it.

Comment: I believe moderators can merge questions. What happens when they do that, and both original questions had accepted answers? Could it result in two accepted answers in the merged question? Just speculating.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: That was not the case for this question. This is a single, unmerged question. I saw both the accepted ticks appear on existing answers when I reloaded the page.

Comment: @JonasCz The OP [accepted and unaccepted various answers 8 times, all within 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30250633/timeline#rev-302506752015-05-15-03-14).

Comment: @BrockAdams The system must have though ... "Maan you click so many times and so fast .... here accept two answers and get away with it" :P

Comment: Interesting, but both answers were accepted in the same second, specifically `2015-05-15 03:02:59Z`

Comment: @DavidG He might fail the Turing test for that speed :P

Comment: I'm guessing this bug has been around for a while; maybe even since the start. Funny how long these things can go undetected, even in heavily used systems.

Comment: Small update: developers are aware of this issue and are working to fix it.

Comment: [this can be used to.. umm... make Jon Skeet loose all his reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/266094/unihedron?tab=reputation)

Comment: The first answer accepted was also down voted to the point where it went grey while still being accepted. The OP then selected 'accepted' on the other answer he accepted. At that point, both answered showed as accepted. I don't know if that helps your analysis...

Comment: mine is one of the accepted answers in that question, I was there, the poster didn't do it in small timeframe, it took a few minutes from one to the other. He accepted mine first, then the other(he should keep the second one BTW, mine has an edge case) I was actually wondering how that was possible!

Comment: @Javier Interesting. In the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30250633/timeline), the system thinks the final two accepts happened at least within the same second (3:02:59, seconds visible on mouse-over). Assuming your observation is correct, I wonder what the cause of the discrepancy was. Your answer *was* accepted just under a minute earlier then unaccepted, before both were re-accepted, perhaps the intermediate events didn't show on your end, and you saw the first accept at 3:02:27 only.

Comment: hmmm it could be, the page didnt refresh to the client as fast, hence my time difference feeling. The weird thing is, why that guy marked 2 answers as correct with 10 seconds difference. That tells me he didnt even analyzed mine or his answer.

Comment: I think we need to give special badge for the op.

Comment: Now what? Should the question in question remain with two accepted answers?

Comment: Should someone check that this behavior cannot be done with bounty rewards as well?  That would be a quick way for some people to get a lot of reputation.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It was a known server-side issue, one that we encountered years ago with [question closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19299/possible-race-condition-with-migration).

However, this was the first case of it affecting accepted answers, most likely from extreme latency in the OP's requests and their propensity for clicking the checkmark on every answer to their question, all within a few seconds.

Server-side locking has been added and I'll look at better locking in the UI (right now, it only prevents multiple requests on the same answer, as in the double-click case).

Comment: Does this fix address the exploit shown in the reproduction script?

Comment: Yes, the requests would execute serially now; only a single accepted answer can exist on a question at a given time (unless there's another bug somewhere else :)

Comment: Nice! Good job :) Perhaps the UI issue could be solved by using the same mechanism you used to use for comment throttling except the trigger would be accepting answers. Or even make it similar to the vote fetching script. Food for thought.

Comment: Race conditions fixed in such an impeccable amount of time is impressive.

Comment: Check out with other potential vote paths (reopen, delete, undelete ;)

Comment: "their propensity for clicking the checkmark on every answer to their question" - those who abused the bug were using scripts, I doubt they even clicked once.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Jarrod is referring to the post reported by Greg here, not to the later abuse.

Comment: [It's back!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334016/4099593)

Comment: @BhargavRao That's a 6 year old question. Maybe they just didn't clean up the existing ones.

Answer (score 160):

Reproduced: [Undefined subroutine called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561226/undefined-subroutine-called)

I did this with code similar to the following JavaScript code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    $.post('https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21561488/accept/1', {fkey: '...'});
    $.post('https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21561472/accept/1', {fkey: '...'});
}
```

Seems to be a race condition.

---

Fun fact: omitting the `fkey` parameter results in a [418 I'm a teapot](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2324) response.

Comment: The reputation of both users for that question looks off. [+135, -60](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1521179/amon?tab=reputation) and [+45, -90](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213907/keepcalmandcarryon?tab=reputation)

Comment: @Cicada we can conclude that Stack Exchange is bad at concurrency.

Comment: Maybe they should ask a question on SO.

Comment: I left a comment for them just in case they are wondering what the heck happened.

Comment: @Cicada:  Oh, man, that's EVIL!  Now I'm off to rep-soak some enemies. }:-)

Comment: Not only are the answerers both (all) penalized rep, but it costs the OP too.  [Rightfold lost 16 points duplicating this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1804599/rightfold?tab=reputation#rep-page-container).

Comment: Certainly not a coffee server!

Comment: Do I get a gold star for breaking the API?

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn three gold stars. As in GTA.

Comment: Now this leaves me wondering ... Can you also accept *three* answers? :-)

Comment: Expect at least 6-8 more weeks of being able to accept multiple answers.

Comment: At least [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) wasn't to blame

Comment: Perhaps this code should be obfuscated or removed to avoid abuse. There was already a user suspended for using this as an attack vector.

Comment: @BrockAdams Why is everyone penalized rep for this? I could understand the answerers (because it thinks that the accepting was undone), but why is the asker penalized?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI - Every time you uncheck an accept you lose 2 points. I would assume that this is part of a multi part transaction where only part of the transaction takes place. The reputation lost from unchecking is not replaced when rechecking as an answer has already been accepted. Just a hunch.

Comment: @TravisJ I see, he kept unaccepting and accepting. But then why does the accepted gain appear multiple times?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI - Unsure, definitely undefined behavior taking place.

Comment: @TravisJ It would be way more fun to just convert it into a snippet and let natural selection take its course.

Comment: @JasonC Stack Snippets run on a different domain (with rendered page inserted in an iframe),  they cannot do anything on SE site itself.

Comment: @Yes Silence. Reality is irrelevant.

Comment: Let's get the answer score to +418 for good measure

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Hm, I tried with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28250680/timeline) (not inflicting harm on other users), but all I got was unaccepting all answers by sending accept requests.

Comment: I've fixed this issue and removed one of the accepted answers - you might want to check that I removed the correct one.