# Status of "Vote to change accepted answer" or user preference on how answers are sorted

Tags: feature-request, voting

First of all - I know this has been asked many times, like:

[Deemphasise the accept mark if there's an answer the community strongly prefers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253752/deemphasise-the-accept-mark-if-theres-an-answer-the-community-strongly-prefers?lq=1)

[Can a non-asker of a question change the accepted answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294815/can-a-non-asker-of-a-question-change-the-accepted-answer)

[Why are negative score accepted answers still at the top?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255706/why-are-negative-score-accepted-answers-still-at-the-top?lq=1)

[Can we exempt downvoted accepted answers from getting the top spot?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178439/can-we-exempt-downvoted-accepted-answers-from-getting-the-top-spot)

However, more and more often I find myself in situation where I find some Q&A on StackExchange and then try to apply accepted answer's suggestion only to find that below accepted answer there is better answer that has like 5x votes. Take a look at this Q&A for example:

[Capture screenshot in GenyMotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771416/capture-screenshot-in-genymotion)

I am definitely not alone with this problem considering number of "+1", "this should be accepted answer" and similar comments. And sure, I could try to force myself to ALWAYS scroll below accepted answer, but considering lots of people are running into this problem I am wondering:

- Is this something that StackExchange devs are looking into?
- I understand that "vote to change accepted answer" would be too big of a change. Even changing the default sorting so that **MOST VOTED answer is on the top** is possibly a big change. Well, would having a per-user setting that would go with **always sort by VOTES** something we could all agree on?
- I mean - **you can set default sort of answers by *Activity* but not by *Number of Votes*** - I really don't understand why.

So, am I missing something here, or this is something that will be taken care of? Is there a "consensus" within community on this?

**EDIT:** I found this Q&A - [Firefox extension/userscript to prevent accepted answer from sticking to top on Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18392/firefox-extension-userscript-to-prevent-accepted-answer-from-sticking-to-top-on) - it does exactly what I am asking here, but I am still wondering if this is something on which there is "consensus" within community and something that StackExchange developers will look into implementing.

Comment: I have this problem too. Another case in point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350779/bootstrap-variable-overriding-with-less What is SO's reasoning behind having the non-OP accepted answer overriding the natural "sort by votes" order?

Comment: I guess they have since implemented this, since I can pick 'Votes', which says it sorts by score. I have that as my user preference but still get whatever crap the asker picked at the top of my results. I guess it's a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like SO are [declining to do anything about this](https://twitter.com/shog9/status/821920332600721408) even tho one could say [it's a defect in the principal goals of the service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341850/56145).

[image: declined status]

Comment: Comments before down votes folks! Btw: this answers the question, which was querying for the status. So I supplied the status.