# Should language-specific gold badge users be allowed to alter correct answer marking?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, accepted-answer

Recently the following question was bumped and it brought to my attention the fact that there are quite a few old questions now whose "correct answers" are no longer correct or perhaps just not completely accurate relative to other newer answers given changes in the language or a standard.

[Is list::size() really O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228908/is-listsize-really-on)

This is just one of many questions (and probably not even the best example) in the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) question field where this can be applied due to the large changes in the standard brought about when [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) was released. I'm sure this applies to other languages too which have seen big changes since the old 2008/2009 questions were asked on this site.

So, with that said, I propose that users whom have a gold badge in a specific language topic should be able to alter the correct answer of a question such that anyone searching for answers finds the correct one as of the current language standard. This could be done via a voting system similar to flags and could also be restricted to older questions (e.g. impose a 5+ year limit since the question was asked for this feature). Alternatively, this could be added as an option when flagging answers to avoid needing to create a whole new feature.

Comment: IMO better solution is to [unpin the accepted answer from the top](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326095/3853934).

Comment: The checkmark is 1 000 % the OP's prerogative. No need to change anything. Giving less weight to the acceptance, yes, would make sense.

Comment: Alright, makes sense I guess. Not sure why this received so many downvotes, my first question on meta so maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury meta downvotes don't mean you made a mistake, just that people don't agree. That's why they don't cost you any rep. It's nothing to worry about, just rethink your feature request (in this case, it sounds like people would rather unpin the accepted answer).

Comment: see also: [Can a non-asker of a question change the accepted answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294815/can-a-non-asker-of-a-question-change-the-accepted-answer)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The checkmark is supposed to be a way for the OP to signify what *helped them*. If that is indeed why they checked it I can't presume to think they are wrong or that it did not help them. Sure, sometimes it gets marked incorrectly but votes should help determine which content is the most useful to the *community*.

The linked discussion about [removing that marked answer from being pinned the top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326095/3853934) might be a better way to address this.

Comment: `I can't presume to think they are wrong or that it did not help them`  Sure you can.  Question authors aren't omnipotent.  Of course, while you are free to reflect your *own* opinion of the post you aren't able to remove the feedback of others.  So yes, you can't remove any evidence that they thought it was good, but you can *absolutely* disagree with them that it is in fact good.

Comment: True. That is why I show my disagreement in the form of a vote on another answer.