# Multiple accepted answers to a question?

Tags: discussion, bug, accepted-answer

This question I found here has multiple accepted answers. How is this possible?

Also note that none of the answers are moved to the top.

[Foreach for an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896227/foreach-for-an-array/3896240#3896240)

[image]

Comment: Wait... what?! That's weird. Also notice how neither answer is moved to the top.

Comment: Looks like a software bug. I flagged it for moderator attention.

Comment: if you hover over the tick it says *"loading when this answer was accepted"*.

Comment: According to the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3896227/timeline), they were already accepted when they were posted.

Comment: @Cerbrus it seems they are still in the sort order you set at the top. on mine the -2 is bellow the 0 because i order by votes

Comment: Stuff like this has happened before: [How did this question get two accepted answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294342/how-did-this-question-get-two-accepted-answers)

Comment: Looking at [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/535412/duplicate-accepted-answers), there's no `AcceptedAnswerId` for this question. My guess is that there's 2 "Accept" votes in the `Votes` table, though.

Comment: It can't be a duplicate of a [meta-tag:status-completed] bug, it's clearly still an issue.

Comment: I imagine this post stealthily walking up to Jarrod and saying *Guess who's back?*

Comment: Note : those questions are from 2010, so pretty old.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha also note that there is no accepted answer in both of the user accounts for this question.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: I suspect this case just didn't get noticed yet. Maybe the bug is fixed, but not all the data resulting from it is "fixed".

Comment: IDK if it has been "fixed" or not but I see no accepts when I visit the post.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm guessing that Martijn [deleting and undeleting](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3896240/timeline) sorted it out. Probably [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com).

Comment: Interestingly, none of the answers on that question have ever had an actual accept vote recorded for them. So somehow the checkmark got activated for them without any vote ever being recorded. I highly doubt this bug still exists, though. It likely got fixed or disappeared many years ago and posts never got cleaned up.

Comment: @Cerbrus [nope](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/535609) - zero accept votes. This confirms animuson's comment above.

Comment: @Glorfindel: isn't the votes table empty on SEDE?

Comment: No, [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/535609) are the results for another random [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935307/uialertcontroller-not-showing-when-moved-to-another-swift-file?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @animuson did a one-off cleanup ran?

Comment: @Braiam A moderator deleted and undeleted the two answers, which apparently resets the accepted status on them (I've no idea how deletion works in relation to accept votes).

Comment: Awwwww, you ruined it:(