# A post so nice, I upvoted it twice (actually, 10 times)!

Tags: bug, status-completed, upvotes

I upvoted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71182310/17242583), but I guess the server was slow because it didn't process right away. So I reloaded the page (and at that very moment for a fleeting second I saw a red banner saying the upvote failed). Then, I clicked upvote again, and the post immediately went from score **2** to **4**!

[image]

Now, it might be fake somehow, because I believe [the answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1599751/peterj?tab=reputation) had 5,530 reputation before this, and now they have 5,541 (+11 more).

I know that sometimes the score of a post will be inaccurate due to caching. Viewing the vote breakdown usually refreshes that, so:

[image]

Comment: What is the first picture supposed to say? +10 rep would be for *receiving* an upvote, not for *giving* one. So this can hardly be your rep breakdown - what makes you think both are yours?

Comment: Probably what happened is, you loaded the page, tried to upvote but didn't see it go through, meanwhile somebody else upvoted the same answer. You refreshed the page and saw the cached version of the vote total, then you upvoted and saw it go up by 2 because it refreshed the vote total from the server, which was now (correctly) 4 including the other person's vote and yours.

Comment: @richardec Probably a weird coincidence of someone else upvoting the same post as you during your page refresh... maybe you could replicate this behavior with downvoting? That way you would be 100% sure the bug occurred when viewing your own rep page due to the diabolical -1 reputation penalty

Comment: @kaya3 I guess that's possible, but it's extremely far-fetched.

Comment: @MFerguson I edited the post and then downvoted it. Now look at its score. It's **1**.

Comment: What is going on? I first saw it as +4. Then +2, +5 and now +4 (?!). OK, [14 registered events](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1599751/peterj?tab=reputation).

Comment: Now it is at +12 (a few seconds before that it was +7)... And now +1 (+2/-1).

Comment: May I remind the esteemed researchers that playing around with votes to repro crosses the line a little bit? :)

Comment: Yeah, there's some meta effect voting going on. FWIW, I pinged a CM to see if they can definitively prove or disprove this

Comment: Now exactly [100 events](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1599751/peterj?tab=reputation)...

Comment: @Machavity nope, there's no meta effect going on. That was all me. I reloaded the page and click the upvote icon over and over again since it didn't activate right away. Everytime the upvotes got undone, the answerer lost 10 rep, I guess, because how else did he go from 5.5k to 5.3k rep!?!?

Comment: My vote is locked on that post now, because I've voted 30 times, so I can't experiment anymore.

Comment: Here's what PeterJ's rep history for today looks like for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub9Wa.png

Comment: How often may this behavior have gone unnoticed?

Comment: The key curation question is, does this work for downvotes ;-)

Comment: I can definitely reproduce this and even works on other posts.

Comment: @Dharman maybe it has to do with that particular user? I wasn't able to on other posts, but I tried again on another of his answers and did it again. Could it be because he votes so much? (~120 every single day)

Comment: @richardec I can do it on posts from other users too. I don't know what it depends on.

Comment: I mean, [look](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1599751/peterj?tab=activity&sort=badges). PeterJ earned 2 bronze badges through this fake voting.

Comment: Yes, please do not abuse this bug

Comment: Anyone tempted to abuse this bug should review [this comic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlXTC.png).

Comment: Someone *has* very recently abusing this - PeterJ now has 2.9k rep vs. his original 3.5k.

Comment: Lol, the vote history on this post is a mess.

Comment: I noticed my rep banner says +54 for the day but as above my rep has gone down over 500.

Comment: Yes - a word to the wise: if one *must* test this bug, it is perhaps not a good idea use the Stack Overflow (or any) main site as a testing location, particularly when one's tests target real people. I _especially_ discourage folks from continuing to use PeterJ's linked answer as test platform. Even though I suspect there will be no lasting issues, that's not a guarantee, and in the meantime it makes for some shockingly confusing UX.

Comment: @Slate: I advise testing on Meta because no rep.

Comment: @PeterJ I'm sorry about all this! I didn't mean to use your account as a test - I was actually asking you something and in doing so I also upvoted. Twice ;)

Comment: Reminds me of this bug back then in 2015 when [a single user could dump someone's rep](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=3449394#3449394) using [this method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294374/2821954)...

Comment: PeterJ's sacrifice has a valuable outcome though. It all reminds us to keep *thinking before doing*.

Comment: The rep seems to have been corrected. Hopefully, we can get an explanation of what caused this mishap.

Comment: @41686d6564 it's actually still happening. The votes on the links answer were reset, I assume, because my vote on it was no longer there. I was going to add my vote like normal, when I noticed the same lag that enabled the multiple votes. Today.

Answer (score 47):

I have posted on MSE regarding the full solution to this (since it will apply to all sites). Please read there: [Upcoming cleanup of duplicate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379788/upcoming-cleanup-of-duplicate-votes).

TLDR:

- Yeah, it is a real issue, since day 1 of the site. Around 13K duplicate votes on SO since then.
- We'll be invalidating all the dupes over the next week, and following that there will be a daily cleanup job.
- Please continue to not try to take advantage of this. We will be able to tell, and will consider these to be in the same league as other types of voting fraud.

---

> duplicate voting
> will be cleaned up very soon
> thanks for the info